# WordPress theme does not support paypal

Tags: wordpress, plugins, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a WordPress website in which default payment gateway is stripe, but I need PayPal. But this theme stop PayPal support, So what I need to do for using PayPal in this theme.
theme is: http://demo.hellovideoapp.com/

Comment: And your question is...

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit PHP pages of the theme on which you want implement PayPal Payment method or whatever you want. Also you need to edit your configuration file i.e. web.config (via CPanel if your website is published).

For further help please check the following documents and code samples:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK